# How to have a Word VSTO Custom Task Pane for more than one window?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-word, vsto

I'm creating a Word Add-in which displays a custom task pane.  This pane is then bound to the ribbon to be shown or hidden (simply by changing the visibile property).

After loading a first document, I can see the task pane. However, when I open a new document (which opens a new window), the visible toggle button keeps checking (and thus hiding/showing) the custom task panel associated with the *first* window.

How do i set the window property on the custom task pane to display it correctly.  (Perhaps always show it in all windows?)

Comment: You need to share your code for relevant context. How are you locating the Task Pane from the Ribbon, etc.?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264456%28v=office.12%29.aspx for more info

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly I was doing it wrong, I expected to have one taskpane shared across all windows, but i needed a taskpane per window.  So every document open/new I create one and associate it with the current window.